# Using Openschema to read Excel files in Powerbuilder

Tags: excel-2007, powerbuilder

I would like write a script in **Powerbuilder** 11.5 in order to read **Excel** files from **Powerscript**.

I am looking for an example powerscript code as a guideline for it!

Any asssistance is kindly appreciated.

Thanks.

John.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sybase [has a good example using OLE posted](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=47867). They also have an example [connecting to Excel through ODBC](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=47700) and [treating Excel sheets as tables with ODBC](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=44462).

Good luck,

Terry.

---

I neglected the title in composing the original answer; my answer may not be applicable. I'm not sure how you could leverage Openschema.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need a script to get Excel values and store in powerscript variables in Powerbuilder. Any assistance on it ?

Comment: Modifying the Sybase example, substitute xlsub.cells[r,c] = dw_1.object.data[r,c] with var = xlsub.cells[r,c].